# ORA-12154 при подключении через PL/SQL к PDB

Tags: oracle, plsql

Расклад такой - есть Oracle 12c версии 12.1.0.2.0, на ней развернули контейнерную БД cdb121, в ней открыли подключаемую БД cdb121pdb1.
На локальной машине для PL/SQL Developer в tnsnames.ora прописали подключение к обеим базам данных:

```
> CDB121PDB1 =   (DESCRIPTION =
>     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mymachine)(PORT = 1521))
>     (CONNECT_DATA =
>       (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>       (SERVICE_NAME = cdb121pdb1)
>     )   )
> 
>  CDB121 =   (DESCRIPTION =
>     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mymachine)(PORT = 1521))
>     (CONNECT_DATA =
>       (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>       (SERVICE_NAME = cdb121)
>     )   )
```

Пытаюсь подключиться через PL/SQL Developer - выкатывает ошибку:

> ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Самое интересное - подключение к другим БД есть стабильно. Использовал SQL Developer для подключения - приконнектился и по сервиснейму, и по TNS-соединению.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? На локали прописаны все параметры окружения. Машина с БД mymachine стоит на Линуксе.

Вывод `lsnrctl status`

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                07-MAY-2018 12:43:50
Uptime                    42 days 1 hr. 0 min. 25 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /oracle122/product/12.2.0/db/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle122/diag/tnslsnr/mymachine/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mymachine)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "6b9b9371eaef3f68e053c005140aa2ee" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb122", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "6e98f7ddc4d53291e053c005140a40e2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb122", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb121" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb121", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb121XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb121", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb121ac740" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb121", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb121autodeploy" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb121", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb121pdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb121", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb122" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb122", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb122XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb122", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb122pdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb122", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb122sm" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb122", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL>
```

Возможно, конфликт с Ораклом 12.2, стоящим там же, надо посмотреть, есть ли listener.ora на моей версии, спасибо, [0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217579/0xdb)

Comment: Добавте в вопрос вывод `lsnrctl status`.

Comment: Выглядит вроде хорошо. Всё должно конектится. Я так понял, только с PL/SQL-Developer проблемы, а всё остальное работает?

Comment: Да, всё остальное работает. SQL Developer 18, использующий тот же tnsnames.ora, спокойно коннектится, а тут прямо какой-то затык. не даёт покоя тот момент, что на иксовой машине стоят две разные версии оракла, и только в одной из них есть листенер, это может как-то повлиять?

Comment: Листенер обычно только один. И проблема не в нём по моему. Скорее всего на локальной машине несколько  tnsnames.ora и находится не тот который нужен. Попробуйте подключить без TNS, только easy connect.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Ларчик открывался очень просто. В файле tnsnames.ora аккурат прямо перед подключением стоял пробел, потому и не было подключения. Пробел убрал, файл заработал. Будьте аккуратны, ребят.

Answer (score 2):

Это основное синтактическое правило для конфигурационных файлов.
Цитата из гл. [Syntax Rules for Configuration Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/syntax-rules-configuration-files.html#GUID-BC580F9E-7A62-4F75-998B-22F6D468FDEA):

> parameter=(keyword=value)
>
> Any keyword in a configuration file that begins a parameter that includes one or more keyword-value pairs **must be in the far left column of a line**. If it is indented by one or more spaces, then it is interpreted as a continuation of the previous line.

То есть, так работать не будет:

```
$ egrep "^\s+\w" tnsnames.ora
 pdb1 =

$ sqlplus -l me/me@pdb1

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```